# multiplying values for specific line

Tags: line, notepad++, multiplication

I am a noob in programming but I need to work this out..

I am using notepad++, and I have a specific line which repeats 1000s times, and each has a different value.. One of them looks like this:

```
wp_galpha=(0.2519)
```

what I need is to reduce the number in brackets by multiplying with.. for example 0.90, so is it possible to change (multiply) every wp_galpha value without doing it manually? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You probably should copy those lines into a script and then use regular expressions with back references in your script to replace your values with the multiplied ones. Don't think that this is possible directly in your editor. But I might be wrong as I don't know notepad++.